# Find $\int_0^3f(x)+f''(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Suppose $f\in C^2[0,3]$ with $f(0)=1$ and $f(3)=3$. Find $\int_0^3f(x)+f''(x)dx$

Integration by parts gives

$$\int_0^3f(x)=[xf(x)]_0^3-\int_0^3xf'(x)dx=8-\int_0^3xf'(x)dx$$

I am not sure how to deal with $f''$, the difficulty here is there is no information about the second derivative. I think I only need some hints

Answer (score 1):

I think we can't  find it,this following two example,all such $$f(0)=1,f(3)=3$$
such as
$$f(x)=x^2-\dfrac{7}{3}x+1\Longrightarrow \int_{0}^{3}[f(x)+f''(x)]dx=\dfrac{15}{2}$$
but
$$f(x)=\dfrac{1}{3}x^2-\dfrac{1}{3}x+1\Longrightarrow \int_{0}^{3}[f(x)+f''(x)]dx=\dfrac{13}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

The problem is wrong.

Let $g(x) = \frac {2}{3} x + 1$ and $f(x) = \frac {2}{9}x^2+1 $

And $g(0)=f(0)=1 ,g(3)=f(3)=3$

However,  $g''(x) = 0 \Rightarrow \int_{0}^{3} (\frac {2}{3} x +1)\mathrm dx=6 $

$f''(x) = \frac {4}{9} \Rightarrow \int_{0}^{3} (\frac {2}{9} x^2 +\frac {13}{9})\mathrm dx=6 +\frac {13}{3}$

Answer (score 0):

Answer:  If we make the following modification to the problem, may it is solvable.

For example, if we have $f'(0) = 1$ and $f'(3) = 3$,

then find $\int_{0}^{3} \left[f'(x) +xf''(x) \right]dx$

Let $g(x) = xf'(x)$

$g'(x) = f'(x) + xf''(x)$

Thus I = $\int_{0}^{3} g'(x)dx = g(x)|_{0}^{3} = g(3) -g(0) = 3f'(3) - 0f'(0) = 3*3-0*1 = 9$

Just for fun now that I spent a lot of time on this.

Thanks
Satish